# MongoDB Trasnform string array to string concatenated in alphabetical order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HxuvWvv3PC0)

Lets say I have this collection:

```
[
  { "Topics": [ "a", "b" ] },
  { "Topics": [ "x", "a" ] },
  { "Topics": [ "k", "c", "z" ] }
]
```

I want to transform this string array to a single string with the itens of it in alphabetical order. The result would be:

```
[
    { Topic: "a/b"},
    { Topic: "a/x"},
    { Topic: "c/k/z"}
]
```

How can I project this result? Using Map? Reduce?

I have Mongo 5.0

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HxuvWvv3PC0)

cheers

Answer (score 1):

just found the solution after some tries...

Just A Unwind, Sort, Group, Project with Reduce made the job...

Data

```
[
  {
    "Topics": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Topics": [
      "x",
      "a"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Topics": [
      "k",
      "c",
      "z"
    ]
  }
]
```

Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Topics"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "Topics": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      Topics: {
        "$push": "$Topics"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      Topic: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$Topics",
          initialValue: "1T1",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              "/",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "Topic": "1T1/a/x",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001")
  },
  {
    "Topic": "1T1/c/k/z",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")
  },
  {
    "Topic": "1T1/a/b",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do this is

- unwind
- sort
- group by id
- reduce to 1 string

Bellow is a way to not unwind all collection but do a "local unwind".

Query

- lookup with a dummy collection of 1 empty document `[{}]`
  (this is "trick" that allows us to use stage operators like sort inside 1 document array) you need that collection in your database
- unwind topics, sort them, group in 1 array, reduce them and create 1 string
- we will have only 1 joined document (the transformed root document),
  we replace the root with that
- remove the "/" from start (it could be done on the reduce stage also)
- added one extra case where topics are empty array to return ""

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kH3HqvPGa1Z)

```js
db.topics.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "dummy",
      "let": {
        "topics": "$Topics"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$set": {
            "Topics": "$$topics"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$Topics"
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "Topics": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "Topics": {
              "$push": "$Topics"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "$set": {
            "Topics": {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$Topics",
                "initialValue": "",
                "in": {
                  "$let": {
                    "vars": {
                      "s": "$$value",
                      "t": "$$this"
                    },
                    "in": {
                      "$concat": [
                        "$$s",
                        "/",
                        "$$t"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "joined"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$joined",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            "Topics": ""
          },
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$joined",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "Topics": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$gt": [
              {
                "$strLenCP": "$Topics"
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            "$substrCP": [
              "$Topics",
              1,
              {
                "$strLenCP": "$Topics"
              }
            ]
          },
          ""
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Nice solution, but in this mean time, I´ve found almost samething of yours but with less stages... take a look https://mongoplayground.net/p/SAH8aeWvuaA

Comment: oh ok i was writing this that he dont need this, i just added it for the "local unwind"

Comment: the common solution is the one you did, but global unwind is problem, imagine having 1 million documents and each array like 1000 members, global unwind  and global group back, in big numbers its bad, especially in sharded collections.

Comment: Nice to know, I will study about. Thanks!